# using wmctrl to close windows

Tags: window, wine

Can I close a window using `wmctrl` that is running in wine on Ubuntu?

For context:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

Also:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x0240a3be -1 mjol N/A
0x02000003  0 mjol Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x0200004c  0 mjol Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x01e00024  0 mjol x-nautilus-desktop
0x04800253  0 mjol using wmctrl to close windows - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
0x03c0c8c3  0 mjol Terminal
0x03c53f25  0 mjol Terminal
0x04400001  0 mjol Untitled - SketchUp
0x04400003  0 mjol Instructor
0x04400009  0 mjol SketchUp
```

The window I want to close is the last one:

```
0x04400009  0 mjol SketchUp
```

I've tried the following:

```
$ wmctrl -c "SketchUp"

$ wmctrl -c 0x04400009

$ wmctrl -i 0x04400009

$ wmctrl -c -i 0x04400009
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a little late, but first seen now.
Reading the info for wmctrl, it says that the correct syntax is  'options' before `actions`, and `-i` is an option, `-c` an action. Try  `wmctrl -i -c 0x04400009`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same question and just found how to do it!

Here's the one-liner that will **gracefully close all Google Chrome windows**:

```
wmctrl -lix |grep 'Google-chrome'|cut -d ' ' -f 1 |xargs -i% wmctrl -i -c %
```

**Explanation:**

`wmctrl -lix` list all windows including their Id and Class

`grep 'Google-chrome'` grep only windows with Google-chrome class (this is important because when you use a site with the app/shortcut option it gets it own class like 'calendar.google.com.Google-chrome'

`cut -d ' ' -f 1` cuts the output to get only the IDs column

`xargs -i% wmctrl -i -c %` passes each ID to the `wmctrl` using the ID **option** `-i` and close **command** `-c`

**Note:** the xargs only worked when I used the `-i` option to specify replace-string. Otherwise it would only act on the first item.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/wmctrl.1.html), you should **select** the window first using a select option, like `-r` and `-a`, exemple :

```
$ wmctrl -l      
0x01800006  0 hostname Terminal - byobu

$ wmctrl -a Terminal
```

Here indeed selects (and raises + focus due to `-a`) the terminal window.

Then you can use a resize / move option such as `-e gravity,X,Y,width,height`

As for your question, I just tested this :

```
$ wmctrl -l                              
0x01800006  0 machine_hostname - byobu
0x06800002  0 moe Microsoft Excel - Classeur1
```

And Excel (obviously running in Wine) closed gracefully when I entered

```
$ wmctrl -c Microsoft
```

Plenty of additional info [here](http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html).